# How to lazily load a collection annotated with eager

Tags: java, hibernate

I have an entity with a relationship mapped as `@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)` and in some cases I'd like to override this fetch mode.

I've tried using Criteria's `setFetchMode` but it didn't work. I also tried using `FetchProfiles` but also no luck.

I've tried writing a SQL query and using the methods `setEntity` and `setRoot` so my entity would be automatically populated but even so it loads the relationships eagerly.

As a hack I also thought to create a second entity extending the first one so I'd override the getter to replace the `@ManyToOne` annotation but when I do so, it results in the following exception:

`org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: XXX column: AAA (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")`

Unfortunately I'm dealing with legacy code and I can't change the annotation type since it'll affect the entire application with `LazyInitializationException`.

Any thoughts?

Comment: AFAIK you can't and if you can it will be very troublesome to change this. I opted for having two configurations for this entity in form of XML file (I don't really like annotations for Hibernate/JPA)

Comment: I tried to find a answer to this question last year, but it appeared that it is not possible. you can locally transform a Lazy to a Eager by doing a join fetch in a query, but unfortunately you can't do the opposite

Comment: NamedEntityGraph maybe, see https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/persistence-entitygraphs002.htm